# jquery to change form target value

Tags: jquery, forms, attributes, target

I need to make a button's target different from the main submit value. I am using jquery with code below:

HTML:

```
<form action="somepage" id="cartform" target="_parent" method="post">
```

(So default action is parent)

JQUERY:

```
$("#refresh").click(function(){
    $("#cartform").attr('target', '_self');
});
```

("Refresh" is the form's extra button to keep the form in a popup box)

Comment: So what's the question? What's the problem?

Comment: So, does that not work? Are there any errors?

Comment: Thanks for reply - it doesn't work! I can't see why not, jquery works fine in general.

Comment: seems to work ok here..... http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/4xhMF/2/ 
Does your button have the id="refresh"?

Comment: my button code is <input type="button" class="button" id="refresh" name="update_cart" value="something"/> - I tried type=submit but no effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add a listener on submit instead of click:

```
$('cartform').on('submit',function(){
   $(this).attr('target', '_self');
});
```

Obv it's the case only if you always want the target to change as the form is submitted. Otherwise, try with your code and `preventDefault`.

```
$("#refresh").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("#cartform").attr('target', '_self').submit();
});
```

I think the form is being submitted before the `target` change applies.

---

## Edit

Actually, OP is trying to submit a form inside an iframe. This should work:

```
$("#refresh").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("#cartform").attr('target', 'name_of_the_iframe').submit();
});
```

Will submit to:

```
<iframe name="name_of_the_iframe" ...
```

Comment: What is the point in preventing default action and then anyway submitting?

Comment: Force the browser to submit _after_ the attribute change. If the form is already being submitted, there's no point to change target as you won't submit it again.

Comment: It will anyway submit *after* the handler run.

Comment: Well, you're right, in my first example there's no need for preventDefault :-) i'll edit it.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately not working - it's still just going to _parent.

Comment: mmh... try with `.removeAttr('target')` instead of `.attr('target', '_self');` or let's see a code sample

Comment: Did not work - but sorry to not have mentioned it's in an iframe (I just said popup) in wordpress - apart from that just standard form html - it does have id= and name= attributes if that helps?

Comment: This refreshed the page the iframe sits on but closed the iframe (it's a popup fancybox from a link on the page) - can you advise how to keep it open? Thanks so much!

Comment: Uhm i don't know as i never used fancybox to submit forms in an iframe... Maybe there's another listener which is closing the popup after you submit the form. Try to find it and remove it.